# Jquery what is different between space with selector and find

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery with two ids selector to find the dom element for getting value.

For example1:

```
$('#id1 #id2').val(); // not working
$('#id2', '#id1').val(); // not working
```

when i execute this i got result as **undefined**

But i execute with find instead of space selectors i got exact result

For example2:

```
 $('#id1').find('#id2').val();//working fine
```

Why this example1 is not working?

What is different between space with selectors and find in jquery?

previously space with selectors is working fine. Now what i did really don't know its not working.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Show the HTML. Most likely you have duplicate IDs.

Comment: Can you please show us your HTML?

Comment: @juhana - i am unable to paste this lengthy html page. But your correct i have duplicate ids on that page. This #id2 is duplicated

Comment: Yeah well, that's the problem. You can't have duplicate ids.

Comment: @Juhana - Thanks for your kind help juhana. But this #id1 is different  i mean container id is different for this #id2. any other way to get that value and solve this issue

Comment: From the ID Selector API: Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid.

Comment: Use classes instead. You can't have duplicate ids regardless of what their container is (or you can, but it will never work as you inted it to.)

Comment: Yeah Ok and again thanks for your help!.